# using nsattributedstring and nslocalizedstring

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, nslocalizedstring

My old code uses NSLocalizedString to display the following where outputText was an NSMutableString that contained many such lines in a single output session:

```
[outputText appendFormat: NSLocalizedString(@"\n\n%@ and %@ are identical.  No comparison required.", @"\n\n%@ and %@ are identical.  No comparison required."), self.ipAddress, secAddress.ipAddress];
```

I'm trying to change the color of the various ipAddress strings, but can't find a similar method when using NSMutableAttributedString.

The biggest problem I'm facing is that since this entire string will be localized, I can't reliably set the NSRange without breaking up each part of the formatted output.

Do I need to dissect each part of this string, convert it to NSAttributedString and append each piece to the outputText??

Comment: I imagine you could regex it out very easily, seeing as numbers don't really change from their arabic numeral forms in commonly localized formats.

Comment: Ugh - you're right.   I'd blocked out regular expressions after I was done with BGP.

Thanks for the reality check!

Comment: You could use `rangeOfString:` to get the range of the inserted strings after inserting them. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: yes.

Yes, you need to localize sections with different attributes separately.

Comment: But that does take into account the use case where parameters order is reversed in the localized string, for instance `"(%1$@, %2$@)"`. That's why an `-(id)initWithFormat:...` method would be great in the `NSAttributedString` class, don't you think ?